# Strange Path.GetFullPath different behaviour between .Net 4.6.1 & 4.6.2 for file path ending with 0x85 char (windows 8)

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am not able to find the reason for this strange Path.GetFullPath behaviour between .Net 4.6.1 & 4.6.2 for file path ending with 0x85 char (windows 8).

Code:

```
var _originalPath = @"D:\user\/web.config." + (char) 0x85;
string _fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(_originalPath);
```

Using 4.6.1 this returns correctly: 
*_fullPath = D:\user\web.config*

However if I switch to 4.6.2 then it becomes: 
*_fullPath = D:\user\web.config.*

(See the extra **dot** remains!!) :(

I am missing something but am not able to figure out what.

Can someone knowledgeable in this area please help explain/solve this??

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public class Program
  {
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetVersionFromRegistry();

        var _originalPath = @"D:\user\/web.config." + (char) 0x85;
        string _fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(_originalPath);

        Console.WriteLine(_fullPath);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Why do you define the first as the "correct" way of working? .NET 4.6.2 did change things a bit by allowing long paths to be used by default. I'm sure this is the result of that.

Comment: Why are you using (char) 0x85?

Comment: This code is used to check against the possibility to access (deny-access) certain files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to repro this, but this change in behavior could be related to the support for long filenames that has been added in .NET 4.6.2. According to the [release notes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/), you can always switch back to the earlier behavior by putting the following into your app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Very sorry but there is no such version value. perhaps you meant sku, like this (which I have already tried and that also does not work):  
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>

Comment: I also tried this UseLegacyPathHandling=false option but that also does not work. :(

Comment: @Deb: Well, this answer was just a shot in the dark, as I'm not able to repro this issue. I just had a look at the reference soure of `GetFullPath` which calls [`NormalizePath`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,9d69b1f37ab42ca1). This method branches on the legacy path handling option, so it would seem reasonable that this could have any relation to your observations.

Comment: hey @dirk thanks for the heads-up and help - tested again and indeed UseLegacyPathHandling=true (not False!!) however makes it working again in .net 4.6.2 :)